# Is it okay to validate JSON at PostgreSQL side?

Tags: java, php, json, postgresql

Writing APIs I used to validate all input parameters on the Java (or PHP, whatever) side, but now we moved our DBs to PostgreSQL which gives us great JSON features, like building JSON from table rows and a lot more (I didn't find anything we can't to without PGSQL JSON-functions so far). So I thought what if I do all parameters validation to Postgres (also considering that I can return JSON straight from database)?

In Java I made it like this:

```java
if (!params.has("signature")) 
//params comes from @RequestBody casted to JSONObject
    return errGenerator.genErrorResponse("e01"); //this also need database access to get error description
```

On a Postgres I will to that like this (tested, works as expected):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.testFunc(_object JSON)
  RETURNS TABLE(result JSON) AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF (_object -> 'signature') IS NULL --so needed param is empty
  THEN
    RETURN QUERY (SELECT row_to_json(errors)
                  FROM errors
                  WHERE errcode = 'e01');
  ELSE --everything is okay
    RETURN QUERY (SELECT row_to_json(other_table)
                  FROM other_table);
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And so on...

The one problem I see so far is that if we move to MS SQL or Sybase it will need to rewrite all procedures. But as NoSQL comes more and more now, it seems to be unlikely and If we move to NoSQL DB we will also have to recode all APIs

Comment: Was your problem finally solved? Which road did you take?

Comment: @joanolo I made some conclusions and answered my own question (you can read it below), so I'd say to leave most logic at Java responsibility, because it allows you to make everything universal, for example `ErrorDetail` object, you can customize it on a DB side, but errors can come not only from database validation phase, that will cause you to prepare the same error object on a DB and Java side. I can tell you more of my thoughts if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found some keys... The main is that I can have my error messages been cached in my application that will allow to avoid making database request if input parameters doesn't pass it and only go to database to get the result data

Answer (score 5):

You have to consider basically two items:

1. The closer you put your checks to the data storage, the safer it is. If you have the database perform all the checks, they'll be performed no matter how you interface with it, whether through your application, or through some third party tool you might be using (if even only for maintenance). In that sense, checking at the database side improves **security** (as in "data consistency"). In that respect, it does make all the sense to have the database perform the checks.
2. The closer you put your checks to the user, the fastest you can respond to his/her input. If you have a web application that needs **fast response times**, you probably want to have the checks on the *client* side.

And take into consideration an important one:

3. You might also have to consider your **team knowledge**: what the developers are more comfortable with. If you know your Java library much better than you know your database functions... it might make sense to perform all the checks Java-side.

You can have a third way: **do both checks in series**, first application (client) side, then database (server) side. Unless you have some sophisticated automation, this involves extra work to make sure that all checks performed are consistent. That is, there shouldn't be any data blocked at the client-side that woud be allowed to pass when checked by the database. At least, the most basic checks are performed in the first stages, and all of them (even if they're redundant) are performed in the database.

If you can afford the time to move the data through several application layers, I'd go with safety. However, the choice to be made is case-specific.

Comment: I agree with you, but I forgot that getting error description also needs access to database , so I guess I'll not get speed advantage making check on a java side... So I should think deeply on your advices. Thanks.